# Chrome DevTools - Performance recording non-responsive or code issue?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm measuring performance via Chrome's DevTools on a web app that puts anywhere from one point to thousands of points on a Google map (mostly custom markers). The issue is that I cannot tell if Chrome's DevTools has "stopped responding" (in quotes because it's not actually non-responsive, but the performance being measured seems to flat-line), or it's pointing to a code problem.

To reproduce, I start the performance recording, turn on the markers (again, can range anywhere from 1 to thousands), zoom / pan around the map, sit idle for a few seconds, stop the recording. Here is a typical result:

[image: devtools screenshot]

As you can see in the image, at some point the CPU meter quickly climbs to and stays at 100%, Frames are no longer measured, function calls seemingly never finish, JS Heap and Node readings flat-line (the function call that supposedly never finishes this time is pointing to google's common.js - however, it's almost always different with every reading...sometimes it's our own files, other times it's jQuery.min, etc - I do *not* think think this is a Google or jQuery problem).

**What is DevTools telling me** - that it's performance is no longer accurately being measured, or that the code is wrecking havoc on the CPU and memory?

If you notice, "Interactions" are still being captured (ex - mouse move, scrolls, etc), so this is leading me to believe that DevTools is still recording, but I'm unsure if the "CPU" and "Main" readings are accurate.

**Local setup:**

- Windows 10 pro (64-bit)
- 16gb ram
- 8 core
- 1TB SSDHD

**Front-end setup:**

- Google Maps (v3)
- Front End (Angular / Jquery / Javascript)
- Chrome Version 61.0.3163.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Do you also see tab's CPU at 100% in Chrome Task Manager (Shift-Esc)? Anyway, this might be a bug in Chrome 61 so try Chrome Canary 63.

Comment: @wOxxOm Chrome's Task Manager's CPU fluctuated between 15-25% during this time, but not any higher

Comment: If you have a 4-core CPU, in Windows it shows 25% for a maximum.

Comment: @wOxxOm that's interesting...I have more (will update the question with my specs)